# GDAL SQL syntax to add field an put values

Tags: sql, ogr

I try to make a new field in my attribute table and put in values from another field after converting from character to integer but can't get the right syntax. I run this as shell-script in MSYS.

```
cd D:/GIS_DataBase/CorineLC/shps_app_and_extr/
myfile=extr_and_app.shp

name=${myfile%.shp}

ogrinfo $myfile -sql "ALTER TABLE $name ADD COLUMN code_num int(3)"
ogrinfo $myfile -sql "UPDATE TABLE $name SET code_num = CONVERT(code_06 As int(3))"
```

Error Message (MSYS):

```
Kay@KAY-PC /c/users/kay/desktop/bash
$ sh calc_field_shp.sh
Warning 6: Unsupported column type 'int'. Defaulting to VARCHAR
INFO: Open of `extr_and_app.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error
INFO: Open of `extr_and_app.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
```

## Edit - Another go with SQLite:

```
cd D:/GIS_DataBase/CorineLC/shps_app_and_extr/
myfile=extr_and_app.dbf

name=${myfile%.dbf}

ogrinfo $myfile -sql "ALTER TABLE $name DROP COLUMN code_num"

ogrinfo $myfile -sql "ALTER TABLE $name ADD COLUMN code_num integer(3)"
ogrinfo $myfile -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE $name SET code_num = CAST(code_06 As integer(3))"
```

Error message:

```
Kay@KAY-PC /c/users/kay/desktop/bash
$ sh calc_field_shp.sh
INFO: Open of `extr_and_app.dbf'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
INFO: Open of `extr_and_app.dbf'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error
INFO: Open of `extr_and_app.dbf'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @R.K., I added the error message to the op.

Comment: have you tried CAST instead of CONVERT?

Comment: I did without success..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because UPDATE is not supported in [**OGR SQL**](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html), as you stated in a comment, you should update the table using the [**SQLite SQL dialect**](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html) available in **GDAL >= 1.10 with SQLite and SpatiaLite** support:

```
ogrinfo $myfile -sql "ALTER TABLE $name ADD COLUMN code_num integer(3)"
ogrinfo $myfile -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE $name SET code_num = CAST(code_06 AS integer(3))"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the CAST operator as [dmci](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9950/dmci) has mentioned like so

```
ogrinfo $myfile -sql "UPDATE TABLE $name SET code_num = CAST(code_06 as int(3))"
```

The SQL dialect supported by OGR does not have CONVERT if recall correctly. You can [check the docs](http://gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql.html) for more info. Good luck!

Comment: Seemingly `UPDATE` is not supported, see here: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-ogrinfo-sql-UPDATE-td5000037.html However, it should be in SQLite dialect but I had no luck with that, either..

Comment: What version of GDAL are you using?

Comment: I'm using gdal-17

Comment: The SQLite dialect needs [GDAL/OGR 1.10](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql_sqlite.html "GDAL/OGR 1.10").